# Filling in spreadsheet text using R

Tags: r, excel

I am looking for a way to fill in a blank column with values based on text in a different column. The column containing the fill in criteria is a job Title and I need to pull out key words that will be used to fill in the column needed. An example of the spreadsheet with Title and Job Role column headers:

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

The goal would be to say if the Title contains "HR, Human Resources" fill in HR in the Job Role column and if Title contains "IT, Information, Technology" then fill in IT in the Job Role column.

I have tried using Excel formulas but keep running into limitations like too many arguments or not being able to properly nest multiple statements.

Let me know if something is unclear or if anything needs to be explained more.

Thanks!

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Using `dplyr` and `stringr` packages, your solution could look like this:  `new_df <- mutate(old_df, job_role_2 = case_when(str_detect(Title, "(HR|Human Resource)") ~ "HR", str_detect(Title, "(IT|Information)")~"IT", TRUE ~ "Other"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you read the spreadsheet into R, you could probably just run the following:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df){
   if(JobTitle[i] == "HR, Human Resources"){
      JobRole[i] <- "HR"
   }
}
```

Although you'll have to change the name `JobTitle` and `Job Role` depending on what the names of the columns end up being. More if statements could be added for different job titles and roles as well.

It would also be more helpful if you incorporated some reproducible code in the question too.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your response. This is definitely the right idea of what I'm trying to do. My df = List_Import1 and the Job Title column header is just "Title" and the blank column I want the results in is "Job Role". Here is the formula of what I used in Excel if it helps.


    IF(SUM(COUNTIF(E2,{"*HR*","*Human Resource*","*People*","*Recruit*","*Talent*","*Learn*","*Benefit*"})),"HR","",)


    IF(SUM(COUNTIF(E2,{"*IT*","*Information*","*Technology*","*Application*","*Architect*"})),"IT","")